# CSS inline-blocks alignment

Tags: html, css

I created several boxes and inside them typed **1**. Except the one in which nothing is typed all others are perfectly aligned. Why does the one with no text moves upwards?

If I type **1** inside the box; it gets aligned now. Why with **no text** it fails getting aligned?

```css
    .box{
        display: inline-block;

        color: red;
        font: 6em monospace;
        margin: 2px;
        border: 2px solid black;

        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(yellow, black);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box"></div>
```

**This is result after typing 1** ->

```css
    .box{
        display: inline-block;

        color: red;
        font: 6em monospace;
        margin: 2px;
        border: 2px solid black;

        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(yellow, black);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
```

Comment: You can add `vertical-align:top`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan first snippet if you full page and get all boxes on one line, the last box is pushed to the top and the rest are middle or baseline

Comment: ```vertical-align:top``` worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

vertical-align is relative to the current text line, not the full height of the parent div. As comented by Carsten, you can set a top value and get all boxes aligned

```
vertical-align: top;
```